# Can I set li padding to auto so that it fits properly to the ul width?

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS

```
#aznav
{
    padding:0;
    width:980px;
}

#aznav li
{
    display:block;
}

#aznav li a
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
    background-color: #333333;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
}

#aznav li a:hover
{
    background-color:#9B1C26;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:2px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    margin:-1px;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<ul id="aznav">
    <li><a href="#">Artist Names:</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">N</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Q</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">U</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

The list above has a padding of 8px.  But I wanted it to be 'auto' and so that it fit the ul width of 980px.

The strict width is 980px. I can't go beyond that, and when I play with the padding, it seems to ignore my set width.

Any ideas?

## FINISHED

Thanks to TJ, I got exactly what I needed.  The example he gave me was just about perfect, but I had lost some of the formatting, as I had in the example above.  To rectify that, I used first-of-type on li.  The final css code that I am using is below.  It makes an attractive and simple horizontal menu, if anyone is interested.

```
#aznav
{
padding:0;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;
background-color: #333333;
}
#aznav li:first-of-type
{
width:50px;
}
#aznav li
{
display:inline;
width:3.3%;
}
#aznav li a
{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
padding:8px;
background-color: #333333;
color:#ffffff;
border-bottom:1px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
}
#aznav li a:hover
{
background-color:#9B1C26;
padding-bottom:8px;
border-bottom:2px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
margin:-1px;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you want the `li` elements to be centered in your element that has a width of 980px? Or do you want the contents of each `li` element to stretch so wide that it touches both sides?

Comment: I want the li elements to be centered in ul (ul needs to be 980px.) But I want the li elements to have even spacing so that it spans the whole width of ul.

Comment: Do you want them all vertically listed? Or listed horizontally and then wrapped?

Comment: I want them listed horizontally. They shouldn't wrap.  They should stretch evenly to 980px.

Comment: Start by removing your `float: left` and changing `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/462/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ancient browser support is not an issue, You can make use of css3 [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) property, By applying

```
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;
```

for the `<ul>`

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3Ezx2/463/)

[justify-content @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Thank you!  There aren't many sites that look right on ancient browsers anyhow. This is just what I need.